# Converting RTF to plain text and back to rtf

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, yui

I'm currently working on Operation Transform model for collaborative editing of documents.
I've implemented a customized form of YUI editor, to provide for rich text editing. I am able to parse plain text from the entered rich text easily, this is used to make the insert/delete operations for collaborative editing. However to reconstruct the original rtf format, i'll need to re-insert the tags(ex: **..** etc.). Does anyone know of a tool/library/online editor which will let me do it easily ?

Thanks in advance for any responses

Comment: isn't this something you would want to do server side?

Comment: how can there be collaboration if not through server then?